# Preferred way of getting absolute path of path relative to current directory

Tags: perl

I am trying to expand a path relative to the current directory:

```
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;

use Cwd;
use File::Spec;

my $fn = 'test/my_file';

say File::Spec->rel2abs( $fn );
say Cwd::abs_path( $fn );
```

Here, `Cwd::abs_path()` fails if directory `test` does not exist.

Why does `File::Spec->rel2abs()` work fine, while `Cwd::abs_path()` fails?

The documentation of the two modules [`Cwd`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Cwd) and [`File::Spec`](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Spec) gives little clue why this happens. According to the following bug report it could be due to expansion of symbolic links, first from 2004: `"Cwd::abs_path returns undef for non-existent paths"`:

- [bugs.debian.org](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=257568)
- [rt.perl.org](https://rt.perl.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=117423)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

File::Spec and the friendlier Path::Class do not touch the file system, so they can be used for path that you will create. `Cwd::abs_path` does, so it can be used to return valid paths. Use whichever is most appropriate.

Comment: Thanks for the reference to `Path::Class`!